# Airport Time Capsule - check backups with another laptop

Tags: macos, backup, time-machine, time-capsule

My laptop is dead. I got an AirPort Time Capsule, and I want to check if there is a fresh backup inside. But because my laptop doesn't start up anymore, is it possible to use another computer to check the backups of my dead one?

Thanks!

Comment: You should be able to get into the Time capsule with the same identity and see what is there...

Comment: Thanks for the answer @SolarMike. What do you mean by the same identity? I want to use the macbook of another person to check the backups